# SSL certificate files - no .ca file

Tags: web-services, http, ssl, web

I am creating an application which requires ssl cert files. It requires `.crt, .key, .ca` files, but I only have `.crt, .key, .pem, and .p12` files. Is the `.ca` file required? What exactly are those files? Is it possible to obtain `.ca` from `.pem` or `.p12`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Self-signed SSL Cert or CA?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/292732/self-signed-ssl-cert-or-ca)

Comment: I really am surprised you asked this question considering how high your repo score is. It's a question whose answers abound everywhere on the web. And many in stack-overflow itself :) You should definitely have researched this before asking this question.

Answer (score 4):

The .ca file is the Certificate Authority Root Certificate. It's the certificate that all the modern browsers have already in their resource as a trusted certificate. When your web-site is requested, your web-server will send his particular certificate + the .ca certificate... and then the browser will find out that you are indeed enrolled with that particular .ca and thus are trusted.

Without this .ca file, the browsers will fail to verify you. The communication will be encrypted and ssl'ed but the user will get a scary warning that says, this site is not protected.

If you have obtained your ssl from any of the vendors, then they will definitely be able to provide you the .ca file.

Where did you get your ssl certificate from?

For each of those file types, you can very easily wiki the types and read more about it. Just so you know, the .key file is your private key and you should take care not to lose it or to keep it somewhere unprotected. If you've actually purchased an ssl certificate, then the .key should be saved and backedu p nicely. .pem and .p12 are different containers for your certificate. Please research the topic..before asking the questions. there are many many answers on StackOverflow and other places as well for this!

Comment: IIRC it was OpenSSL. And I used `.pem` file just now (instead of `.ca`), and it works just fine...

Comment: aah iirc?? i had to google that first.. LOL .. openSSL isn't a certificate authority. It's just a program that creates private-public keys... these aren't trusted certificates, and hence you don't have a .ca file. To get a .ca file, you need to BUY a certificate.. from one of the vendors. 

sslshopper.com will have a lot of information regarding this.